# objective c perform selector in background and autoreleasepool

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing an iphone application which has some data stored in a sqllite database. When my view loads i would like to load the data from the database on a background thread. The problem is the application keeps crashing and i dont know why.

The code:

```
-(id) init
{
    if((self=[super init]))
    {
       [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadList) withObject:nil];
    }
 }

-(void) loadList
{
   @autoreleasepool
   {
      Loader * loader = [[Loader alloc] init];
      NSMutableArray * array = [loader getItemList];
      [array retain];
      NSLog(@"Got %d items",[array count]);

      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(createList:) withObject:array waitUntilDone:false];
      [loader release];
   }
}

-(void) createList: (NSMutableArray*) array
{
    items = array;
    int i;
    Item * it;
    for(i = 0; i < [items count]; i++)
    {
      it = [items objectAtIndex: i];
      [it getName]; // crashes
      // populate the list
    } 
}
```

Loader returns a NSMutableArray with Item objects. The application crashes when i call the item getName (which returns a NSString*). From what i understand it crashes because the item name properties is being released. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You're aware that SQLite isn't really thread safe? See http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6 and the various considerations mentioned below. This is a comment rather than an answer since I've no reason to believe it directly affects your current problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely to be a problem with whatever type of object you're using to populate `array`.

I'm unable to find finger-on-paper proof but I'm confident that `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` retains its object. However if each of the items in `array` keeps a reference to `loader` then they need to take responsibility for retaining that object. It looks like you're attempting to keep it alive manually but — as Chuck alludes to — your call to `performSelector...` will return instantly and not wait for the call you've made to complete.

Comment: the objects in the array don't have a reference to loader, they only contain attributes from the database. I've replaced the the waitUntilDone to YES and it doesn't crash anymore at getting the name. But now there is a different problem it crashes when accessing a different property of the object. It looks like that some properties were released and some weren't. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

This particular bug appears to be that you're passing `waitUntilDone:NO`, so the array is being released immediately and consequently so are its items.

But in general, UIKit is not thread-safe, so this is just a touchy design. I would probably put the loading of this stuff in another class that handles the task for you instead of right in the view.

Comment: Isn't the extra [array retain] keeping the array from being freed? If not, [items count] or [items objectAtIndex] would crash first.

Comment: i have changed the waitUntilDone to YES and it fixed the problem. But now it crashes when accessing some other property of the object in the array. The strange part is that the name works fine but other properties crash it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put a breakpoint on the line:

```
 it = [items objectAtIndex: i];
```

Then type

```
po it
```

in the debugger, and see what's in the name field.  As a guess, I'd say one of two things: 1) the field that getName returns isn't initialized with an object (i.e. isn't a real NSString *) or that you're getting a C string from SQLite (which is what it usually returns) and you're trying to treat it as an NSString *.  If it's the latter you can use [myCString stringWithUTF8String] to convert the C string into an NSString *